# Drupal 8: Best practice to get nid in form_submit

Tags: 8

I can get nid from within form_submit by using one of those snipet:

```
$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->id()
```

or

```
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')->id()
```

If feel this is a little bit overkilling... what is the best way?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Could you expand on what you mean by "overkilling"? What would the method that you want to be able to use look like? Your first example looks absolutely perfect, what specifically do you find to be overkill about it?

Comment: I was thinking that the number of the function call was high to just get the nid. But I am happy by your answer: I asked this question to be sure that I don't miss something (more simple). Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `$node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()`.

Oh, saw that you actually mentioned that. This is the correct way to do it.